# NTLM Authentication in Android

Tags: android, ntlm

I am developing an Android application which access Sharepoint Web Service and does SOAP processing. I tried various ways like JCIFS, etc. Nothing worked.

Could any one help me here? I googling it from many days, but everyone who has this issue is frustrated.

Thanks,
Indrajit

Comment: Did you find an adequate solution?  I am facing a similar issue with OkHttp

Answer (score 12):

I'm not expert in NTLM but I successfully connected to our backend using JCIFS library and some manual work with the headers.

I also use OkHttp 3 library for network connection, but you could probably adapt my code to other libraries.

The main idea is that you have to negotiate with the server to connect.

**Step 1:**

When you try to connect the 1st time you'll fail and receive some information in the header:

WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

WWW-Authenticate: NTLM

**Step 2:**

You need to generate a Key of type 1 (with optional domain & workstation parameters) using the jcifs library, and try to connect again.
You'll fail again but receive some useful information in the header:

WWW-Authenticate: NTLM very_long_challenge_key

**Step 3:**

You need to generate a Key of type 3 with that challenge key + login + password, using the jcifs library. Then the connection will succeed!

Now some code, add the dependency to the libraries in the build.gradle file of your app:

```
compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.18.jar')
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

The jar can be found here: https://jcifs.samba.org/src/

Then the NTLMAuthenticator class

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import jcifs.ntlmssp.NtlmFlags;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;
import jcifs.util.Base64;
import okhttp3.Authenticator;
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.Route;

/**
 * Created by Arnaud Guyon on 07.02.17.
 */

public class NTLMAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    private static final int TYPE_1_FLAGS =
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56 |
                    NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128 |
                    NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2 |
                    NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN |
                    NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET;

    private String mLogin;
    private String mPassword;
    private String mDomain;
    private String mWorkstation;

    public NTLMAuthenticator(@NonNull String login, @NonNull String password) {
        this(login, password, "", "");
    }

    public NTLMAuthenticator(@NonNull String login, @NonNull String password, @NonNull String domain, @NonNull String workstation) {
        mLogin = login;
        mPassword = password;
        mDomain = domain;
        mWorkstation = workstation;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

        List<String> authHeaders = response.headers("WWW-Authenticate");
        if (authHeaders != null) {
            boolean negociate = false;
            boolean ntlm = false;
            String ntlmValue = null;
            for (String authHeader : authHeaders) {
                if (authHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("Negotiate")) {
                    negociate = true;
                }
                if (authHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("NTLM")) {
                    ntlm = true;
                }
                if (authHeader.startsWith("NTLM ")) {
                    ntlmValue = authHeader.substring(5);
                }
            }

            if (negociate && ntlm) {
                String type1Msg = generateType1Msg(mDomain, mWorkstation);
                String header = "NTLM " + type1Msg;
                return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", header).build();
            } else if (ntlmValue != null) {
                String type3Msg = generateType3Msg(mLogin, mPassword, mDomain, mWorkstation, ntlmValue);
                String ntlmHeader = "NTLM " + type3Msg;
                return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", ntlmHeader).build();
            }
        }

        if (responseCount(response) <= 3) {
            String credential = Credentials.basic(mLogin, mPassword);
            return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String generateType1Msg(@NonNull String domain, @NonNull String workstation) {
        final Type1Message type1Message = new Type1Message(TYPE_1_FLAGS, domain, workstation);
        byte[] source = type1Message.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encode(source);
    }

    private String generateType3Msg(final String login, final String password, final String domain, final String workstation, final String challenge) {
        Type2Message type2Message;
        try {
            byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(challenge);
            type2Message = new Type2Message(decoded);
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        final int type2Flags = type2Message.getFlags();
        final int type3Flags = type2Flags
                & (0xffffffff ^ (NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER));
        final Type3Message type3Message = new Type3Message(type2Message, password, domain,
                login, workstation, type3Flags);
        return Base64.encode(type3Message.toByteArray());
    }

    private int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then when you create your OkHttpClient, add this authenticator:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .authenticator(new NTLMAuthenticator(login, password))
        // .some other init here if necessary
        .build();
```

And then do your requests as usual.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "do your requests as usual"? I'm not familiar with OkHttp

Comment: There are simple samples for OkHttp here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/#overview

Comment: Impressive. Thanks for your work. I advice you to upload this to git. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: What is **Type1Message**??

Comment: Getting java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21

Comment: After sending Type3Message, Negotiate and NTLM is responded as well as i 1st step. That is probably the same @Akash is facing. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Check this...........................

http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/manipulating-sharepoint-list-items-with-android-java-and-ntlm-authentication/