# NTLM authentication in Android app

Tags: android, authentication, ntlm

I'm using JCIFS library found [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html) to use NTLM authentication in my android app.The app worked fine when it just went to a site and parsed an xml, but now that I added the NTLM auth it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone tell from this snippet of code if where the problem is between the httpclient and the inputstream?

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("http://www.musowls.org",80),
new NTCredentials(username, password, null, "musschool"));  
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.musowls.org/assignments/assignmentsbystudentxml.aspx");
 HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
 HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
 InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it may be help you.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());

NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("user_name", "password", "", "http://www.musowls.org/");

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 5000);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.musowls.org/assignments/assignmentsbystudentxml.aspx");
httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // ERROR HAPPENS HERE

responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.d("Responce", responseXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Download JCIFS from here: http://jcifs.samba.org/

2) Follow the instructions here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html

Answer (score 0):

Been stuck on this problem for way too long.

Check out the answer in this thread to use OkHttp3 for NTLM Authenticated calls:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42114591/3708094