# Using JCIFS in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, urlconnection, jcifs

Here is the case: 
I want to authenticate my Android device in code, by sending username and password to specific URL, this URL will have internal and external Access.
through reading [JCIFS Library](https://jcifs.samba.org/) which main job is to connect to windows using NTML, trying to make it works in android, I inserted this code:

```
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                String user = "username";
                String pass = "password";
                String sharedFolder = "shared";
                String url = "smb://url/url//" + sharedFolder + "/test.txt";
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                        null, user, pass);
                SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
                sfile.canRead();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

this sample code I have used for only getting authorization from Windows into my Android application, I just want to return the Auth, not copying files nor comparing between files. 
I have failed after reading [UrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) and [UrlStreamHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) and have tried almost all questions in StackOverFlow but I didn't find an answer.

also when I apply this code, the message that comes is

```
02-21 04:50:02.329 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server
02-21 04:50:02.329 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: jorphp01
02-21 04:50:02.329 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.UniAddress.getAllByName(UniAddress.java:315)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1338)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.canRead(SmbFile.java:1462)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at ils.com.ntmlproject.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at ils.com.ntmlproject.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:882)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1338)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.canRead(SmbFile.java:1462)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at ils.com.ntmlproject.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at ils.com.ntmlproject.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-21 04:50:02.339 3032-3046/ils.com.ntmlproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I don't know if the error is in http protocol ? or in the code? 
what I need to adjust here and what I have missed?

Comment: The host name: `jorphp01` is not resolvable from the device you're running your app on. Try connecting the device to the same network and ensure it goes through the same DNS server which can resolve this host name. Otherwise, you can even try by configuring the IP address instead of host name.

Comment: I need to communicate with this host specifically, this host is the propose from using JCIFS library. but either way, I will try your answer and see. thank you

Comment: When I referred IP address, I meant IP address of this host, which you can find using `nslookup` or `ping`.

Comment: it works ! Thank you !!
The error that was in referring to host instead of IP Address through Android, which does not realize the host name, so what I have changed is the host name to IP address and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host name: `jorphp01` is not resolvable from the device where the code is executed. Below would be the possible solutions:

1. Try connecting the device to the same network and ensure it goes through the same DNS server which can resolve this host name.
2. If the server is reachable, but DNS resolution fails, modify the DNS server configured. Can take help of apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.mytechie.setDNS&hl=en
3. Try configuring the IP address instead of host name in the client application on the device.
4. Modify the /etc/hosts file (on rooted device) to resolve the host name to the preferred IP address. Ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/

Answer (score 1):

I found what case the error and what the solution to my case. 
first thanks for @Pavan Kumar for answer the question and gives me some hints.

1. The server I was trying to reach is not reachable through Android, so instead I have used the IP address of server instead of its name.
2. I have applied the OkHTTP in network connection using jcifs library to connect to my server through this method which works fine in my case:

   ```
   final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResponse);

   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

           HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("http://10.10.6.4/erpapi/").newBuilder();
           String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
           // issue the Get request
           String getResponse = "";
           try {
               getResponse = doGetRequest(url);
               System.out.println(getResponse);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               getResponse = e.getMessage();
           }

           return getResponse;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           textView.setText(s.toString().toLowerCase());
       }
   }.execute();
   ```

and the function is :

```
static String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .authenticator(new NTMLAuthenticator("username", "password"))
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();}
```

the [source of this code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html) , and have used the jcifs library for authentication.

after this I could easily login in to server and sent authenticated.

also these are some useful resources to see from:

[httpclient](https://github.com/kohsuke/jcifs/blob/master/docs/httpclient.html)

[android-ntlm](https://github.com/groupsky/android-ntlm)

[ntlm-authentication-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770581/ntlm-authentication-in-android)

[android-smb-cifs](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/android-smb-cifs-tutorial.17179/)