# DownloadManager Authentication with NTLM

Tags: java, android, ntlm

I want to use `DownloadManager` to download files from my college internet. The site uses Www-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM.

I used the code below to log in but it only works with basic authentication, So how could I make it run with NTLM?

```
 DownloadManager manger = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
 DownloadManager.Request request =  new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
 request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
 final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s","username","password").getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
 request.addRequestHeader("Authorization" , basicAuth);
 request.setTitle("file.pdf");
 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
 request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
 request.setDescription(String.format("Downloading %s", "file.pdf"));
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("MyGucFiles", "file.pdf");
 request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
 manger.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: you cannot ... NTLM needs 2 round trips ... there is no way to implement this with DownloadManager

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770581/ntlm-authentication-in-android

Comment: Yeah thanks it helped alot.

Comment: Is there any solution for this to use download manager with ntlm?